# SqlDateTimeOverflow exception with nullable DateTime fields with Dapper update

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I have a db table with several DateTime fields with null values. These are mapped to nullable DateTimes in my class.

If I try to perform an update with Dapper, within my data layer:

```
 using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(DB.getConString()))
 {
    cnn.Open();
    return cnn.Execute((this.OptionID == 0 ? _insertSQL : _updateSQL), this);              
 }
```

I get a SqlDateTimeOverflow exception (because the DateTime field is '01/01/0001 00:00:00' rather than null.

Is the only way around this to specify each parameter individually and switch the value to null like this:

```
 using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(DB.getConString()))
 {
    cnn.Open();
    return cnn.Execute("UPDATE MyTable SET MyDateField = @MyDateField", new {MyDateField = (MyDateField.HasValue? MyDateField : Null), etc etc... );
```

I have about 50 fields in the table so this would be quite a bit of code, plus there is an INSERT method to update similarly too. Is there an easier syntax I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that `01/01/0001 00:00:00` is *not* a "null value"; if you had used `DateTime?` I suspect it would have worked fine. However, I also have to recognize that `DateTime.MinValue` has often (mainly due to .NET 1.1 lacking nullable structs) been used to *represent* a null value. My preferred suggestion here would be to simply use `DateTime?`. The min-value map is a bit complicated as we might also consider whether that should be automatically mapped instead to the sql min-value (January 1, 1753).

Re the update statement - maybe add an extension method to map between min-value and null?

```
public static DateTime? NullIfZero(this DateTime when) {
    return when == DateTime.MinValue ? (DateTime?)null : when;
}
```

and use:

```
new { MyDateField = MyDateField.NullIfZero() }
```

but again, if `MyDateField` was `DateTime?`, you could just use:

```
new { MyDateField }
```

Comment: Yes, the property is already DateTime? but it doesn't end up as null. For example:  public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }.

Comment: @Simon yes, but what is the **value** in it? A `DateTime?` that has the value `01/01/0001 00:00:00` *is not null*; if you want it to be `null` - store it as a `null`.

Comment: The value is null in the database if that's what you mean?

Comment: The 01/01/0001 was coming from a rogue control on a page, I've fixed this and am now passing in a genuine null, I still get the same exception though. I'll accept this answer and create another question.

Comment: Problem solved, as expected it was entirely my fault, Dapper works fine. I had declared a datetime field as a string by mistake. Great service as usual Marc.